# Ignore a block of code that fails c++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to just ignore a block of code only if it fails to execute in c++? Something like the try - except in python,  it would help me a lot.

I'm trying to make a program that constantly reads some information of a file that contains a number, and then converts it to an integer with stoi().
The problem is that the file is constantly being modified by another program, and at some point the main program may read the file when it is being modified, giving an emty string and making the program fail when trying to convert it to an integer.

What I would like to do is make my program ignore all the loop if the stoi() fails, and simply wait until the loop is executed again to get actualized information. I know that this can be done in python with try and eccept, but I don't know how to do it in c++.

Comment: [try-catch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch)

Comment: C++ has exception handling.   Please provide more detailed information about what you're after.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? I mean the *actual* problem, not just you asking for help with your current solution to the actual problem? Please read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) as your question is a good example of it.

Comment: Some code will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

try block associates one or more exception handlers (catch-clauses) with a compound statement.

For more detail please refer [try catch in c++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch)